# Pip install error on Mac for PyCryptodome

Tags: python, macos, terminal, cryptography, pycrypto

I've tried installing pycryptodome, pycrypto, and pycryptodomex and none of them seem to be downloading. I keep getting this pip install error:

> error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1 Command
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/tn/c5hkkz_94rxfyghjrlzvj4nr0000gp/T/pip-build-Cl1sR8/pycryptodomex/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /var/folders/tn/c5hkkz_94rxfyghjrlzvj4nr0000gp/T/pip-VrIJcG-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/tn/c5hkkz_94rxfyghjrlzvj4nr0000gp/T/pip-build-Cl1sR8/pycryptodomex/

I'm using Mac OSX El Captain currently, I have python 2.7 and 3.5 installed, I'm hoping it will go to my python 3.5. I used the terminal command `pip install pycryptodome` and others switching the names out, none of them seem to work.

Comment: I suspect you don't have xcode installed.

Comment: I have xcode installed

Comment: Have you tried upgrading pip with `pip --upgrade install pip`?